# Change background colour of ListView item based on SimpleCursorAdapter field?

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a custom ListView item using RelativeLayout which looks like this...

```
| Time | Title        |
|      | Description  |
```

NOTE: The lefthand 'Time' is a single full height TextView with 'Title' and 'Description being individual 'stacked' TextViews.

The ListView items represent TV programmes extracted from a SQLite DB with a SimpleCursorAdapter. This works fine but the next step is to indicate when a programme has been scheduled to record (the app is an Android client for a PC-based PVR application).

The SQL query selects 'start_time,title,description,is_set_to_record' the first three being text fields to bind to the TextViews and the last being boolean.

It seems I probably need to extend SimpleCursorAdapter so if 'is_set_to_record' is true then I set the background colour of all three TextViews to a different colour. The problem is that I don't know where I should be looking to do this.

Is this possible? If so, any pointers to where I should look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your extended SimpleCursorAdapter you can do something like this.:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
     Cursor c = getCursor();
     c.moveToPosition(position);
     int col = c.getColumnIndex(is_set_to_record);
     boolean isSet = c.getInt(col) == 1;
     if (isSet) {
         // Set the background color of the text.
     } else {
         // Set the background color to something else.
     }
     return v;
}
```

Comment: I did it in a slightly different way to your example but it was close enough to get me looking in the right direction. Thanks!